# Android Google Maps not working outside my computer

Tags: android, google-maps, api-key

I'm doing a project with two colleagues using Android Studio, where we need to use google maps, however this problem has appeared everytime. When I compile and have the app running on my pc Android Studio everything works great and google maps works however when I send the project to either one of my colleagues when they try and run the app on their phones Google Maps only shows a grey screen, showing only the buttons but not the maps. We share the same keys generated by myself. The minSdkVersion implemented on the project covers all our phones. We have tried several things and none of them seemed to solve problem, like generating different keys for each one of them. 
The only thing that seems to work is if I run the app using their phones through my computer, it's the only way that the app will show the maps.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you sure your keystores are the same? Debug and release?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The API key you've generated does not match their keystore. This key is generated with the SHA1 of your keystore. Make sure you all have the same keystore. Each install of Android Studio creates a new debug-keystore. You should make sure you use the same keystore.

Comment: Could you tell me where can we check the keystore? I don't know where to check for that

Comment: it's located in ~/.android/debug.keystore . Just give the others a copy of yours and let them replace their debug.keystore with yours at that location.