# How to copy the debug.keystore file?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have the same problem with [Android Google Maps not working outside my computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30033295/android-google-maps-not-working-outside-my-computer), and in the solution, it looks like making sure everyone in my team have the same .keystore file will solve the problem. However, .keystore file is hidden, I guess it's also encrypted in some way that you can't just view it using cat command.

I am working with my teammates on a android project and I'm in charge of the map part, but no one else can see the map even if we have the exactly same codes(shared using git).

So could anyone please tell me how to copy the file to others (and is it safe to do so)?

Or is there any other ways to do this?

I use a mac, the I have teammates using windows and mac.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Option a)

You can make everyone on your team use the same signing key for debug builds.

I like this solution because when testing you can easily update already installed apps from your colleagues (because the signatures match).

#### 1. Make a prepro keystore

Copy one of your debug keystores in your project root directory. Debug keystore is typically located in `~/.android/debug.keystore`. Let's name the copy `prepro.keystore`.

#### 2. Make a prepro signing config

In your *app module* build.gradle create a new signing config that's using the keystore from step 1.

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        prepro {
            storeFile rootProject.file("prepro.keystore")
            storePassword "android"
            keyAlias "androiddebugkey"
            keyPassword "android"
        }
    }
}
```

Note the passwords and key alias for all debug keystores.

#### 3. Use the prepro signing config

Make all your debug builds use this new signing config.

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.prepro
        }
    }
}
```

#### Notes

You can name your new signing config anything except `debug` and `release`.

> is it safe to do so

Putting a key in Git is OK as long as it's a key intended for development.

### Option b)

Add your colleagues' debug key signatures to the project Google console. Then apps built by them will be able to use Google APIs such as Maps.

More info here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#getting-the-certificate-information-yourself

> I guess it's also encrypted in some way that you can't just view it using cat command.

Correct, see the link above.

Comment: Best way to do it. Although I'd suggest another, clearer naming than `prepro`, I personally used `sharedDebug`.