# Is it necessary for everyone to have the same keystore to develop an Android app with Firebase Auth?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am creating a Flutter app and using Firebase Auth for authentication. I properly set up everything and created a SHA1 fingerprint with: `keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore`. Some developers working on the same project are getting `PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)` and from what I've already seen online, it is likely and issue with the SHA1 fingerprint. However, it consistently works on my system.

Is it necessary for my fellow developers to use the same keystore as me? or is it necessary for them to run the keytool command and add their SHA1 to Firebase as well? I have little understanding on how this SHA1 fingerprint works.

Is my issue actually related to these keystores? Could the fix for this PlatformException be elsewhere?

Comment: @cutiko Yes, that's what I linked in my own answer.

Comment: That comment was automatic when the question waa flagged as duplicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found an answer from another stack overflow post: [How to copy the debug.keystore file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47621520/how-to-copy-the-debug-keystore-file) It seems everyone on a developer team must be using the same keystore in order for the API calls to work or everyone's key must be added to firebase or else there will be PlatformExceptions. Although the linked answer does not say this, it's necessary to add SHA256 as well for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You can add others SHAs to the project in the web console.

Go to the web console, select the project, click on sertings (the cog icon), select project settings, there in the general tab you can find the app and inside the app you can add more SHAs by clicking `Add fingerprint`.

Comment: I understand how to add more fingerprints. I posted an answer linking 2 solutions that confirm both of my originally proposed methods are valid.

Comment: Then you either mark your own answer as the solution or mine, everybody using the same keystore seems a bad strategy for me.

Comment: I have to wait 2 days to do so.

Comment: You are the OP so is your choice to select a bad strategy as the solution, good luck scaling that

Comment: Could you explain why distributing a prepo keystore to all developers wouldn't scale?

Comment: What are you gonna do when you have more than 1 environment? 1 project for development, another for staging and another for prod. So you are gonna be juggling the 3 things in a mailing list, and be very careful to not share the staging or the prod? If everyone adds their own sha, then everybody can use their own project as a dev environment when the project reaches a more mature step.

Comment: I see what you mean a little better. What did you mean by a mailing list?

Comment: With a more mature development, you will have different environments, so each a time a dev join the team they have to ramp up the project. Create a project on their own Firebase and use a seed for the data, rules at that moment should be under version control so it is normal dev set up. The google service dot JSON is unique for each dev and the staging and prod are secure by excluding them off VCS preventing leakage and miss use. Later continuous integration will have the staging and prod google services dot JSON and nobody but a secure environment will access them, and all starts here.